# Spring boot 2 Multitenant Configuration Not Using Transactions

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I have a Spring boot 2 application that was working well. I introduced Multitenancy configuration and now it's not working any more.

I followed this example: https://medium.com/swlh/multi-tenancy-implementation-using-spring-boot-hibernate-6a8e3ecb251a

As notes: I was using a HibernateTrasactionMaanger, however, during my research it's not needed if you use:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The idea is the DAOs extend a Base DAO where to get the session from. The @Transactional annotation is located in the Services layer, having the services starts transactions as they needed.

Previous to the Multi tenant configuration it was working well, but I was using this configuration with the same application.properties, BaseDao, GenericDao. The only difference was in BaseDao which had a EntityManagerFactory autowired instead the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean it's using now

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class));

        return txManager;
    }

}
```

This is how my app looks like now:

application.properties

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=@database.driverClassName@
spring.datasource.url=@database.url@
spring.datasource.username=@database.username@
spring.datasource.password=@database.password@
spring.datasource.name=prohome_tenant_directory
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=@database.maxPoolSize@

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

PersistenceConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource,
            MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
            CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl
    ) {

        Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>(jpaProperties.getProperties());
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.example.orm", "com.example.orm.tenant");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap);

        return em;
    }

}
```

BaseDao.java:

```
@Component
public abstract class BaseDao {

    @Autowired
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.getObject().unwrap(SessionFactory.class);

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

GenericDao.java:

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T, PK extends Serializable> extends BaseDao {

    private final Class<T> type;

    public GenericDao(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T getById(PK id) throws DatabaseException {

        try {

            return getSession().get(type, id);

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ex);
        }
    }

    public <T> T getEntityByIdAndType(String id, Class<T> entityClass) throws DatabaseException {

        try {

            return getSession().get(entityClass, id);

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ex);
        }
    }

    public T save(T entity) throws DatabaseException {

        try {

            Session session = getSession();

            session.save(entity);

            return entity;

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ex);
        }
    }


    //Other methods ommited.


}
```

Tenant Configuration according the article, I'm using Database per Tenant so this entity lives alone in a DB only to store tenants in a table.:

TenantDataSource.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant_data_source_config")
public class TenantDataSource implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String dbDriverClassName;
    private String dbUrl;
    private String dbUsername;
    private String dbPassword;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 36)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "db_driver_class_name", nullable = false)
    public String getDbDriverClassName() {
        return dbDriverClassName;
    }

    public void setDbDriverClassName(String dbDriverClassName) {
        this.dbDriverClassName = dbDriverClassName;
    }

    @Column(name = "db_url", nullable = false)
    public String getDbUrl() {
        return dbUrl;
    }

    public void setDbUrl(String dbUrl) {
        this.dbUrl = dbUrl;
    }

    @Column(name = "db_username", nullable = false)
    public String getDbUsername() {
        return dbUsername;
    }

    public void setDbUsername(String dbUsername) {
        this.dbUsername = dbUsername;
    }

    @Column(name = "db_password", nullable = false)
    public String getDbPassword() {
        return dbPassword;
    }

    public void setDbPassword(String dbPassword) {
        this.dbPassword = dbPassword;
    }

}
```

TenantDataSourceDao:

```
@Repository
public class TenantDataSourceDao extends GenericDao<TenantDataSource, String> {

    public TenantDataSourceDao() {
        super(TenantDataSource.class);
    }

    public TenantDataSource getByName(String name) throws DatabaseException {

        try {

            Session session = getSession();

            CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<TenantDataSource> query = builder.createQuery(TenantDataSource.class);

            Root<TenantDataSource> root = query.from(TenantDataSource.class);
            query.where(builder.equal(root.get("name"), name));

            TenantDataSource tenant = session.createQuery(query).uniqueResult();

            return tenant;

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

TenantDataSourceService.java

```
@Service
public class TenantDataSourceService {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantDataSourceService.class);

    @Autowired
    private TenantDataSourceDao dataSourceDao;

    private final Map<String, DataSource> tenantDataSources = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Map<String, DataSource> getAll() {

        LOGGER.debug("Initializing ALL Tenant DataSources");

        try {
            List<TenantDataSource> tenants = dataSourceDao.getAll();

            LOGGER.debug("Found {} tenants", tenants.size());

            Map<String, DataSource> result = new HashMap<>();

            for (TenantDataSource config : tenants) {

                LOGGER.debug("Configuring DS for tenant {}", config.getName());
                DataSource dataSource = getDataSource(config.getName());
                result.put(config.getName(), dataSource);
            }

            return result;

        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Can not load ALL Tenant DataSources", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a data source based on the tenant name.
     * 
     * If not exists attempts to create it.
     * 
     * @param name
     * @return
     * @throws DatabaseException 
     */
    protected DataSource getDataSource(String name) throws DatabaseException {

        LOGGER.debug("Requesting dataSource for tenant={}", name);

        //The DataSource was already added just return it.
        if (tenantDataSources.get(name) != null) {

            LOGGER.debug("DataSource for tenant {} was already created", name);
            return tenantDataSources.get(name);
        }

        //Create the data source and add it to the data sources map.
        DataSource dataSource = createDataSource(name);

        if (Objects.nonNull(dataSource)) {
            tenantDataSources.put(name, dataSource);
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a DataSource from the Tenant configuration in the database.
     * 
     * @param name
     * @return 
     */
    private DataSource createDataSource(String name) throws DatabaseException {

        LOGGER.debug("Creating dataSource for tenant={}", name);

        TenantDataSource tenantDataSource = dataSourceDao.getByName(name);

        if (Objects.nonNull(tenantDataSource)) {

            DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .driverClassName(tenantDataSource.getDbDriverClassName())
                    .username(tenantDataSource.getDbUsername())
                    .password(tenantDataSource.getDbPassword())
                    .url(tenantDataSource.getDbUrl());

            DataSource ds = factory.build();    

            return ds;
        }

        return null;
    }   
}
```

TenantIdentifierResolver.java

```
@Component
public class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantIdentifierResolver.class);

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {

        String tenant = Objects.requireNonNullElse(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant(), TenantConstants.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);

        LOGGER.debug("Identified tenant as: [{}]", tenant);

        return tenant;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {

        return true;
    }

}
```

TenantConnectionProvider.java

```
@Component
public class TenantConnectionProvider extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantConnectionProvider.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource directoryDataSource;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    //DataSource map.
    private final Map<String, DataSource> map = new HashMap<>();

    //Init flag.
    private boolean init = false;

    public TenantConnectionProvider() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void load() {
        map.put(TenantConstants.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID, directoryDataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        return map.get(TenantConstants.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {

        if (!init) {
            init = true;
            TenantDataSourceService tenantDataSourceService = context.getBean(TenantDataSourceService.class);
            map.putAll(tenantDataSourceService.getAll());
        }

        return map.get(tenantIdentifier) != null ? map.get(tenantIdentifier) : map.get(TenantConstants.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
    }

}
```

TenantContext.java which is set in a Filter previous to any other action by looking the tenantId in the request

```
public class TenantContext {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> CURRENT_TENANT = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    public static String getCurrentTenant() {
        return CURRENT_TENANT.get();
    }

    public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {
        clear();
        CURRENT_TENANT.set(tenant);
    }

    public static void clear() {
        CURRENT_TENANT.set(null);
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
[2020-05-20 15:32:38,903] [main] [DEBUG] [com.example.tenant.TenantDataSourceService.getAll] [user=n/d] - Initializing ALL Tenant DataSources
[2020-05-20 15:32:38,915] [main] [ERROR] [com.example.tenant.TenantDataSourceService.getAll] [user=n/d] - Can not load ALL Tenant DataSources
com.example.exception.DatabaseException: Database error occurred
    at com.example.dao.GenericDao.getAll(GenericDao.java:134)
    at com.example.dao.GenericDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a026e92f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.example.tenant.TenantDataSourceDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$646b253f.getAll(<generated>)
    at com.example.tenant.TenantDataSourceService.getAll(TenantDataSourceService.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:514)
    at com.example.dao.BaseDao.getSession(BaseDao.java:33)
    at com.example.dao.GenericDao.getAll(GenericDao.java:121)
    at com.example.dao.GenericDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a026e92f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.example.tenant.TenantDataSourceDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$646b253f.getAll(<generated>)
    at com.example.tenant.TenantDataSourceService.getAll(TenantDataSourceService.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
[2020-05-20 15:32:38,927] [main] [INFO ] [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport.initialize] [user=n/d] - Initializing ExecutorService 'emailThreadPoolTaskExecutor'
[2020-05-20 15:32:39,626] [main] [INFO ] [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.getOrDeducePassword] [user=n/d] -
```